# PHP Regular expression for star '*'

Tags: php, explode, preg-split

I have a string ending with '*' or '^'.
For example:

```
$variable = 'abcdef**^^';
```

I used preg_split() function to split the string.

```
$variable = 'abcdef*^^^^';
$words = preg_split("/(?<=\w)\b[!?.]*/", $variable, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

And I got the output as

```
Array
(
    [0] => abcdef
    [1] => *^^^^
)
```

But the problem begins, when my variable is replaced with '@','' and some other special characters.
For Example:

```
$variable = 'abc@d ef*^^^';
```

Output become like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => abcd
    [1] => @ ef
    [2] => *^^^^
)
```

I need the output like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => abcd@ ef
    [1] => *^^^^
)
```

I was trying to replace my current RegEx with RegEx for '*' and '^', But I can't find one.

Comment: `$words = preg_split("/\*/", $variable, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` use this

Comment: What is (in plain English) the splitting rule?

Comment: You can also use this to split on both `*` and `^` `$words = preg_split("/\*|\^/", $variable, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your answers.
I have figured my solution by the references you all given.
I am posting it,May help anyone in future..

```
<?php

$variable = 'Chloride TDS';
if (preg_match('/[\*^]/', $variable))
{
if ( strpos( $variable, '*' ) < strpos( $variable, '^' )   || strpos( $variable, '^' ) === false ) 
{
    $first = strstr($variable, '*', true);

    $last = strstr($variable, '*');
}

if ( strpos( $variable, '^' ) < strpos( $variable, '*' ) && strpos($variable,'^') != '' || strpos( $variable, '*' ) === false ) 
{
    $first = strstr($variable, '^', true);
    $last = strstr($variable, '^');
}
echo $first;
echo '<br/>';
echo $last;
}else{
    echo $variable;
}



?>
```

Comment: You should escape ^ too in your regex

Comment: There're no needs to escape `*` inside the character class.

Comment: @shazyriver: No, he shouldn't inside a character class.

Answer (score 3):

use `\*` for star. below are the example

```
<?php

$variable = 'abc@d ef*^^^';
$words = preg_split("/\*/", $variable, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($words);  
?>
```

and it's output is this

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc@d ef
    [1] => ^^^
)
```

if you want to add * then used this

```
<?php

$variable = 'abc@d ef*^^^';
$words = preg_split("/\*/", $variable, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$i=0;  
foreach ($words as $value) {
    if($i != 0)
    {
        $words[$i]='*'.$words[$i];
    }
    $i++;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($words);
?>
```

Comment: I tried this but my output should be 
Array
(
    [0] => abcd@ ef
    [1] => *^^^^
)

Comment: you want to include * ?

Comment: Can you please check it this condition that $variable = 'abcef*'; or $variable = 'abcef^';
I think its fails.

Answer (score 1):

If i am grasping true meaning of the question, OP mentioned

> I have a string ending with '*' or '^'.

If you want to split the string in this way, you should change the regexp like this.

```
$words = preg_split("/[\*|\^]/", $variable, 2, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

This would break the string on first concurrence of * or ^. OP has already excepted an answer, but i am adding mine in case it helps anyone else in this situation.

**Edit:** You do not need to use preg_split() if you wanna do this. Simply use strstr with a few conditions.

```
$variable = 'abcd@ ef*';
if ( strpos( $variable, '*' ) < strpos( $variable, '^' ) || strpos( $variable, '^' ) === false ) 
{
    $first = strstr($variable, '*', true);
    $last = strstr($variable, '*');
}
if ( strpos( $variable, '^' ) < strpos( $variable, '*' ) || strpos( $variable, '*' ) === false ) 
{
    $first = strstr($variable, '^', true);
    $last = strstr($variable, '^');
}

echo $first;
echo '<br/>';
echo $last;
```

This one is working on every case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,But can you please check these two cases
$variable = 'abcd@ ef*
$variable = 'abcd@ ef^
the string with only one character

Comment: The case you are talking about is something different that means you want to split but keep the delimeter ?

Comment: Yes.I need to keep it.
After a couple of steps I need to concatenate the string.

Answer (score 0):

If your split character is just "*" you can use explode:

```
$words = explode('*', $string, 2);
```

If it's "*" or "^" do this:

```
$words = preg_split("/[\*,\^]+/", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: sometime it may only '*' or '^'
sometimes both